# How to omit the blank between the text and and the pdflscape?

Tags: pdflscape

I have wide table so I need to put the table in `pdflscape` environment. But, I found there are too much blank between the text and the `pdflcape` environment.
[image]

Is there a way to omit this blank?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
On Tuesday’s "The ReidOut," Planned Parenthood Director Alexis McGill Johnson criticized the leaked Supreme Court draft opinion that suggested Roe v. Wade could be overturned.

MSNBC host Joy Reid said the pro-life movement was primarily founded and functions as a push for segregation.

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
She said most religious groups polled do not support the Supreme Court majority that could vote to overturn the 1973 abortion case. 

"This is a super minority position which is being imposed essentially by Christian nationalists, five Christian nationalists on the court," Reid added. "Does it hit you differently to know that this has grown out of this essentially segregation movement?" 

"I think it’s completely consistent with the segregationist movement," Johnson answered.
Vladimir Putin is preparing for a long war in Ukraine, with even victory in the east potentially not ending the conflict, US intelligence has warned.

The warning comes as fierce fighting continues in the east, where Russia is trying to take territory.

Moscow refocussed its troops on capturing the Donbas region after Ukraine resisted attempts to take its capital Kyiv.

But despite this, its forces remain in a stalemate, US intelligence said.

Avril Haines, the director of national intelligence, told a US Senate committee hearing on Tuesday that Mr Putin was still intending "to achieve goals beyond the Donbas", but that he "faces a mismatch between his ambitions and Russia's current conventional military capabilities".

She added that the Russian president was "probably" counting on US and EU support for Ukraine to weaken as inflation, food shortages and energy prices got worse.

However, the Russian president could turn to "more drastic means" as the war continues - although Moscow would only use nuclear weapons if Mr Putin perceives an "existential threat" to Russia.

Defence Intelligence Agency Director Scott Berrier told the same hearing that the Russians and the Ukrainians were "at a bit of a stalemate".

In the latest fighting, Ukraine claims to have recaptured four settlements in the north-eastern Kharkiv region.

Cherkasy Tyshky, Ruski Tyshky, Rubizhne and Bayrak were all snatched back from Russia, Ukraine's arms forces said.

President Volodymyr Zelenskiy said Ukrainian successes were gradually pushing Russian forces out of Kharkiv, which has been bombarded since the war began.

But he said Ukrainians "should not create an atmosphere of excessive moral pressure, where victories are expected weekly and even daily".
\end{document}
```

Comment: Basically, no.  There is an automatic \clearpage when changing to landscape.  But you can improve the look using \afterpage (afterpage package).

Comment: @JohnKormylo You way can resolve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This gets rid of the space between portrait and landscape.  It also gets rid of headers, footers, page numbers, etc.

```
\documentclass[multi={portrait,landscape}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}% not used

\newenvironment{portrait}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{8.5in}%
  \centering\begin{minipage}{345pt}
  \parindent=10pt
  \parskip=0pt plus 1pt}{\end{minipage}\end{minipage}}

\newenvironment{landscape}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{11in}%
  \centering\begin{minipage}{550.0pt}
  \parindent=10pt
  \parskip=0pt plus 1pt}{\end{minipage}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{portrait}
On Tuesday’s "The ReidOut," Planned Parenthood Director Alexis McGill Johnson criticized the leaked Supreme Court draft opinion that suggested Roe v. Wade could be overturned.

MSNBC host Joy Reid said the pro-life movement was primarily founded and functions as a push for segregation.
\end{portrait}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}

\begin{portrait}
She said most religious groups polled do not support the Supreme Court majority that could vote to overturn the 1973 abortion case. 

"This is a super minority position which is being imposed essentially by Christian nationalists, five Christian nationalists on the court," Reid added. "Does it hit you differently to know that this has grown out of this essentially segregation movement?" 

"I think it’s completely consistent with the segregationist movement," Johnson answered.
Vladimir Putin is preparing for a long war in Ukraine, with even victory in the east potentially not ending the conflict, US intelligence has warned.

The warning comes as fierce fighting continues in the east, where Russia is trying to take territory.

Moscow refocussed its troops on capturing the Donbas region after Ukraine resisted attempts to take its capital Kyiv.

But despite this, its forces remain in a stalemate, US intelligence said.

Avril Haines, the director of national intelligence, told a US Senate committee hearing on Tuesday that Mr Putin was still intending "to achieve goals beyond the Donbas", but that he "faces a mismatch between his ambitions and Russia's current conventional military capabilities".

She added that the Russian president was "probably" counting on US and EU support for Ukraine to weaken as inflation, food shortages and energy prices got worse.

However, the Russian president could turn to "more drastic means" as the war continues - although Moscow would only use nuclear weapons if Mr Putin perceives an "existential threat" to Russia.

Defence Intelligence Agency Director Scott Berrier told the same hearing that the Russians and the Ukrainians were "at a bit of a stalemate".

In the latest fighting, Ukraine claims to have recaptured four settlements in the north-eastern Kharkiv region.

Cherkasy Tyshky, Ruski Tyshky, Rubizhne and Bayrak were all snatched back from Russia, Ukraine's arms forces said.

President Volodymyr Zelenskiy said Ukrainian successes were gradually pushing Russian forces out of Kharkiv, which has been bombarded since the war began.

But he said Ukrainians "should not create an atmosphere of excessive moral pressure, where victories are expected weekly and even daily".
\end{portrait}
\end{document}
```